Azure Database Watcher connected to SQL Managed Instance does not show any SQL Managed Instances in Dashboard
I have configured an Azure Database Watcher (preview) to monitor a SQL Managed Instance. After starting the database watcher the Dashboards do not display any SQL Mananged Instance instances.
Here are the verifications I have completed:

Azure SMI is configured with ME-ID and Database Watcher has been assigned access
Azure SMI is within a Private Network and the Private Endpoints section shows an Approved connection
T-SQL statements have been executed on the Azure SMI
Data Store has a configured Database/Cluster

Thanks!

The SQL target can be in any subscription within the same Microsoft Entra ID tenant as the watcher.

This issue can have multiple causes for not showing the Azure SQL Managed Instance on the dashboard as when you start the watcher it takes come time to collect the data.

Verify Azure SQL Managed Instance is running properly and check if firewall is allowing the Database Watcher's IP address for connection.
Check the Azure SQL Managed Instance is correctly added on watcher and able to access the data correctly.
To get exact issue check the logs of watcher if it is connecting properly to database or returning any error or warning.
check the status field if the watcher is running. it will not automatically get started.

check this If you are not able to see the new data within few minutes.
If the issue still persists, contact Azure support ticket for assistance as this feature is in preview.
